# Can't ping local devices while being connected to iPhone USB tethering

Tags: networking, network-manager, ping, iphone, arp

I can't ping devices that are connected to wireless hotspot but I can ping them when my computer is also connected to hotspot wirelessly. And it's not just ping my computer doesn't respond properly to ARP requests, it does response but it doesn't work because it replies with mac address not with IP.
netstat -rn output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.10.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enx422619303333
172.20.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 enx422619303333
```

ip route:

```
default via 172.20.10.1 dev enx422619303333 proto dhcp metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx422619303333 scope link metric 1000 
172.20.10.0/28 dev enx422619303333 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.10.5 metric 100
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem with Ubuntu but a question about how networks operate. If devices are tethered to a phone, they are connected to the cell phone provider's network, not your local network. When you connect your machine to the same hotspot, you are now in the same local network segment, which allows you to query them. Keep in mind that iOS does filter some types of network traffic when operating as a hotspot.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But they are in the same local network. By local devices I mean devices that are connected to the same hotspot with different interfaces. My computer is connected to my iPhone hotspot with USB interface while others are also connected to my iPhone hotspot(wirelessly). I wasn't sure if the issue is because of iPhone settings and I thought it's possible that it's because of network interfaces and filtering in ubuntu.